# why would a simple query have poor performance on MS SQL Server 2014 or 2014SP3 when on other versions it performs well?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2014, query-performance, execution-plan

I am running the following query on MS SQL Server 2014 (and also on 2014SP3)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #GUIDs(
  PartyNames_GUID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
  Party_GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NULL,
  FirstName  NVARCHAR(255)  NULL
)

insert #GUIDs(Party_GUID)
select top 1 Party_GUID 
FROM Party a 
join PartyNames b on a.Party_ID = b.Party_ID 

--Give the optimizer all kinds of choices. 
create  index i1 on #GUIDs(PartyNames_GUID)
create  index i2 on #GUIDs(Party_GUID)
create  index i3 on #GUIDs(Party_GUID, PartyNames_GUID)
create  index i4 on #GUIDs(PartyNames_GUID,Party_GUID)
update statistics #GUIDs


SELECT  PartyNames.PartyNames_ID,       PartyNames.LastName,        PartyNames.FirstName
FROM Party  INNER JOIN PartyNames   ON PartyNames.Party_ID = Party.Party_ID  
            INNER JOIN #GUIDs       ON Party.Party_GUID = #GUIDs.Party_GUID                     --Hard Match on Party_GUID
                                                     AND 
      (#GUIDs.PartyNames_GUID IS NULL OR PartyNames.PartyNames_GUID = #GUIDs.PartyNames_GUID )  --Optional Match
                                                    AND 
            (#GUIDs.FirstName IS NULL OR PartyNames.FirstName = #GUIDs.FirstName )          --Optional Match

drop table #GUIDs
```

Both the Party and PartyNames tables have a clustered index on their primary _IDs, a nonclustered unique index on their respective GUIDs and PartyNames has a index on the foreign key from Party. The DDL for these table is included at the end not so as to not clutter up the description of the problem. Party has about 1.9M rows and PartyNames 1.3M. PartyNames can at the most have 3 records per Party. The above query takes a few hundred milliseconds to run. But the same query runs in 15ms or less on SQL Server 2012, 2016 and 2019. The schema on all versions is the same, the exact same data is BCP'ed in and statistics updated after the BCP is done and before running the query. Here is how the execution plan looks on 2014
[image]
 And here is the execution plan on the other SQL Server versions , 2012, 2016, 2019
[image]

Why does 2014 generate such a poor plan, one which scans PartyNames' primary key rather than seeking on
 [PartyNames].[ix_PartyNames_Party_ID? OR rather how do versions  higher and lower  than 2014 manage to come up with a good plan while 2014 does not ? The plan generated by the other versions is obviously better as it consumes less CPU and does less IOs. Is it some server setting on 2014 which is causing this ? Is the costing the optimizer of SQL Server 2014 that dramatically different from versions before or after it ? Any help or pointers appreciated. I would hate to think this is a shortcoming in SQL Server 2014. And the interesting thing is that even if the number of records are reduced to a few thousand, SQL Server 2014 continues to generate the same bad plan. But removing the last  AND clause ,(#GUIDs.FirstName IS NULL OR PartyNames.FirstName = #GUIDs.FirstName ) causes SQL Server 2014 to generate the same good plan as the other versions.  This is of course a contrived reproduction. Customers running our product on MS SQL Server 2014 complained of poor performance while those on other versions did not. Troubleshooting the issue lead to this simple reproduction.

And here is the DDL for the schema generation

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Party](
    [Party_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Party_GUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_Party_Party_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Party_ID] ASC),
 CONSTRAINT [uq_Party_Party_GUID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( [Party_GUID] ASC)
) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Party] ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_Party_Party_GUID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Party_GUID]
GO




CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PartyNames](
    [PartyNames_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PartyNames_GUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Party_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_PartyNames_PartyNames_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PartyNames_ID] ASC),
 CONSTRAINT [uq_PartyNames_PartyNames_GUID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([PartyNames_GUID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PartyNames] ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_PartyNames_PartyNames_GUID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [PartyNames_GUID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PartyNames]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk_PartyNames_Party_ID] FOREIGN KEY([Party_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Party] ([Party_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PartyNames] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_PartyNames_Party_ID]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_PartyNames_Party_ID] ON [dbo].[PartyNames]
(
    [Party_ID] ASC
)
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable documented and supported trace flag 4199 (which enables query optimizer fixes) to correct this problem.

You can enable it at the query level to test it out, but that requires sysadmin permissions (which hopefully your application doesn't have).  A pretty convincing argument can be made for turning this on globally (as a startup trace flag), you can read some discussion around that here: [Trace Flag 4199 - Enable globally?](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=707)

---

I was able to reproduce your problem using the following test data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Party
    (Party_GUID)
SELECT TOP (1900000)
    NEWID()
FROM master.dbo.spt_values v1
CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v2;

INSERT INTO dbo.PartyNames
    (Party_ID, PartyNames_GUID)
SELECT TOP (1300000)
    Party_ID,
    NEWID()
FROM dbo.Party;
```

Getting an estimated plan for the test query produces the bad plan:

[image: screenshot of the bad plan]

The optimizer chooses to scan the clustered index on `dbo.PartyNames` because, for some reason, it thinks that every row in `dbo.PartyNames` is going to be a match for the one row retrieved from `dbo.Party`.

Adding `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4199)` to the end of the query corrects this faulty reasoning and produces the good plan:

[image: screenshot of the good plan]

For more information on TF 4199, see this KB: [SQL Server query optimizer hotfix trace flag 4199 servicing model](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974006/sql-server-query-optimizer-hotfix-trace-flag-4199-servicing-model)

---

An alternative solution is to use the legacy cardinality estimator with trace flag 9481, which also produces the good plan.

Comment: The fix in this case changes `CSelCalcSimpleJoin` to `CSelCalcSimpleJoinWithUpperBound` see https://www.sqlshack.com/join-estimation-internals/ for details but essentially 1/cardinality is not a great selectivity estimate when cardinality = 1. One could also use the original CE ofc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regarding  9481. I wasn't aware of it. I will try it on my local test server out of curiosity. But I will urge the customer to move to 2014SP3. Thank you all for  your help